# Where does the center of mass torque come from?

Tags: torque

When calculating the torques about a pivot point, there is a torque that comes about if you aren't rotating about the center of mass- where does this torque physically come from? For instance, given a massless rod connecting two point masses of different mass, $M_1$ and $M_2$, one expects there to be a torque that is their mass times their distance from point of rotation. Where does the other force physically come from, if you aren't at the center of mass?

Comment: Do you mean a situation where you have a force acting on the rod, but not in the center of mass? Intuitively I would say that is ultimately a side effect of the rod imposing a condition on both masses to stay at a constant distance.

Comment: I mean, say you have a bar with two masses- looking at the center of the bar, it looks like there are uneven torques, and you would expect it to spin. This isn't the case, because we need to "add in" the torque from being away from the center of mass, but this seems unnatural as we've already taken into account the two masses.

Comment: Without external forces there is no torque, at all. So where does your external force come from? Gravity? Yes, in that case there is a net torque and the mass exerting the larger torque will end up at the bottom after the system has come to rest. In the meantime it will become an oscillating pendulum.

Comment: Oh, more specifically I was considering the bar in free fall, without air resistance. I was confused because I couldn't intuitively explain why it didn't rotate via torque arguments.

Comment: In free fall the only force that exists is the centripetal force that keeps the two masses at a constant distance. There is no torque in that case. As soon as you have a net torque, something gets accelerated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, in free fall the center of the bar of length $\ell$ sees at least the two torques $M_2\ell/2$ and $M_1\ell/2$, but these are uneven, so I would expect it to rotate.

Comment: Please look at the definition of torque, again.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean, do mean because there would be another torque, because we aren't rotating about the center of mass? But physically, why does this extra torque make sense?